# Python code to find common n-grams that exceed a threshold in the same folder

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a python code where I compare multiple text files in the same directory (about 500 files) using n-grams without importing any sophisticated module. What I have done so far with my code is that I have a nested dictionary where the keys for the outer dictionary are the file names and the values are dictionaries of sentences cleaned off punctuation and their n-grams. I am trying to find out how many files have common n-grams in that folder/directory. I iterate through the files and if these common n-grams exceed a certain threshold, both files names are included in a summary/results text file together with that counter value. Here's my code below. Thank you in advance!

```
import glob
import string
import time

def file_processing(D,n):
    
    """
    Function loops through all text files in folder

    Parameters
    ----------
    D : Directory/Folder
    
    n : number of n-grams

    Returns
    -------
    file_dict : Dictionary of files and n-grams
    
    """
    essaydirname=D +"/"
    filenamelist = glob.glob(essaydirname + "*.txt")
    
    #Dictionary of all files in directory/folder
    file_dict={}
    
    for filename in filenamelist:
        
        print(filename)
         #Ignoring errors in input file due to unreadable characters
        with open(filename, 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
            
            #create new dict for cleaned lines stripped to words
            clean_lines={}
            
            for line in f:
                
                # Remove html and punctuation from sentences
                line=line.lower()
                clean_html=remove_html(line)
                clean_punc=remove_punctuation(clean_html)
                words=clean_punc.split() # splitting clean lines
                
                if len(words)==0: # skip blank lines
                    continue
                
                # Generating n-grams
                ngrams=zip(*[words[i:] for i in range(n)])
                
                #Keeping a collection of clean sentences and their n-grams
                clean_lines.update({clean_punc : [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]})
                
                
            file=('.').join(str(filename).split('/')[1:]) 
            # Source file and n-grams kept in dictionary
            file_dict.update({file : clean_lines})
            
            f.close()
    
    return file_dict
            
def find_plagiarised_pairs(data_set_dir,n, threshold):
    
    """
    Function compares n-grams between documents given 
    some threshold and number of grams
    Parameters
    ----------
    data_set_dir : Folder/Directory
    
    n : n-grams
    threshold : integer limit for similarity between n-grams

    """
    
    start_time=time.time()
    
    data_set_dir=file_processing(data_set_dir, n)
    
    counter=0

    for file in data_set_dir:
        
        for i in data_set_dir[file]:
    
            test=(data_set_dir[file][i])
            
            suspect=data_set_dir[file].values()
            
            #Check for plagiarism between two files
            if suspect in test:
                counter+=1
            
        if counter>=threshold:
            #Create a summary sheet of results
            ofile = open("Summary.txt", 'w')
            ofile.write(file + "%7d\n"%(counter))
            ofile.close()
            
    run_time=time.time()-start_time
    print("it took",run_time, "seconds to run code")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need suggestions on how I can improve my code especially the find_plagiarised_pairs function. I want to compare the n-grams that I have generated in the function file_processing for the different files and see how many files have common n-grams. With my current code (i.e., find_plagiarised_pairs), I am unable to do that. I am failing to go through each file in the dictionary and compare the n-grams for each line in the text file. In short, I'm comparing all files in a given folder to check for plagiarism.